# Shift forward/backward causes the data of the moved row to be invisible

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

For dataframe `df`:

```
                x1        x2         y
year_week                              
2019-50   -0.090451  0.022198 -0.231182
2019-51    0.164583 -0.104173  0.016565
2019-52   -1.088672 -1.274486 -1.284807
2020-01    0.211166  0.130683 -0.350436
2020-02   -1.088672 -1.274486 -1.284807
```

I created leading and lagging indicators based on `x1`, `x2` with the following code:

```
df['x1_leading2'] = df['x1'].shift(2)
df['x2_lagging3'] = df['x2'].shift(-3)
```

The result is as follows:

```
                 x1        x2         y  x1_leading2  x2_lagging3
year_week                                                        
2019-50   -0.090451  0.022198 -0.231182          NaN     0.130683
2019-51    0.164583 -0.104173  0.016565          NaN    -1.274486
2019-52   -1.088672 -1.274486 -1.284807    -0.090451          NaN
2020-01    0.211166  0.130683 -0.350436     0.164583          NaN
2020-02   -1.088672 -1.274486 -1.284807    -1.088672          NaN
```

But we saw that some rows disappeared after the move, and the index of "Year-Week" did not increase automatically. How to deal with it? Thanks.

The expected result:

```
                 x1        x2         y  x1_leading2  x2_lagging3
year_week                                                        
2019-47         NaN       NaN       NaN          NaN     0.022198
2019-48         NaN       NaN       NaN          NaN    -0.104173
2019-49         NaN       NaN       NaN          NaN    -1.274486
2019-50   -0.090451  0.022198 -0.231182          NaN     0.130683
2019-51    0.164583 -0.104173  0.016565          NaN    -1.274486
2019-52   -1.088672 -1.274486 -1.284807    -0.090451          NaN
2020-01    0.211166  0.130683 -0.350436     0.164583          NaN
2020-02   -1.088672 -1.274486 -1.284807    -1.088672          NaN
2020-03         NaN       NaN       NaN     0.211166          NaN
2020-04         NaN       NaN       NaN    -1.088672          NaN
```

To generate `year_week` index:

```
def generate_year_week(start_date, end_date):
    import datetime
    current_date = start_date
    year_weeks = []

    while current_date <= end_date:
        year = current_date.year
        week = current_date.isocalendar()[1]
        year_week = f"{year}-{week:02d}"
        year_weeks.append(year_week)

        current_date += datetime.timedelta(weeks=1)
    return year_weeks

import datetime
start_date = datetime.date(2019, 12, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2020, 1, 31)
year_weeks = generate_year_week(start_date, end_date)
print(year_weeks)
```

Out:

```
['2019-48', '2019-49', '2019-50', '2019-51', '2019-52', '2020-01', '2020-02', '2020-03', '2020-04']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) your DataFrame before applying the `shift`. Use a [`PeriodIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.html) with [`period_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.period_range.html) to make the conversion easy:

```
N_BEFORE = 3
N_AFTER  = 2

# convert as PeriodIndex
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index+'0', format='%Y-%W%w').to_period('W')

# generate new periods from expected shift
new_idx = pd.period_range(df.index.min()-N_BEFORE, df.index.max()+N_AFTER, freq='W')
df = df.reindex(new_idx)
df['x1_lagging2'] = df['x1'].shift(N_AFTER)
df['x2_leading3'] = df['x2'].shift(-N_BEFORE)

# restore string index (optional)
df.index = df.index.strftime('%Y-%W')
```

Output:

```
               x1        x2         y  x1_lagging2  x2_leading3
2019-47       NaN       NaN       NaN          NaN     0.022198
2019-48       NaN       NaN       NaN          NaN    -0.104173
2019-49       NaN       NaN       NaN          NaN    -1.274486
2019-50 -0.090451  0.022198 -0.231182          NaN     0.130683
2019-51  0.164583 -0.104173  0.016565          NaN    -1.274486
2020-00 -1.088672 -1.274486 -1.284807    -0.090451          NaN
2020-01  0.211166  0.130683 -0.350436     0.164583          NaN
2020-02 -1.088672 -1.274486 -1.284807    -1.088672          NaN
2020-03       NaN       NaN       NaN     0.211166          NaN
2020-04       NaN       NaN       NaN    -1.088672          NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with necessary values in index:

```
df = df.reindex(year_weeks)
df['x1_lagging2'] = df['x1'].shift(2)
df['x2_leading3'] = df['x2'].shift(-3)
```

For dynamic count first and last datetime for new week index use:

```
#converting to datetimes
idx = pd.to_datetime(df.index + ' 0', format='%Y-%W %w')

N1 = 2
N2 = 3

#count start and end datetimes
start_date = idx[0] - pd.tseries.offsets.Week(n=N2 + 1)
end_date = idx[-1] + pd.tseries.offsets.Week(n=N1 - 1)

#add rows filled by missing values
df = df.reindex(generate_year_week(start_date, end_date))
df['x1_lagging2'] = df['x1'].shift(N1)
df['x2_leading3'] = df['x2'].shift(-N2)

print (df)
               x1        x2         y  x1_lagging2  x2_leading3
2019-47       NaN       NaN       NaN          NaN     0.022198
2019-48       NaN       NaN       NaN          NaN    -0.104173
2019-49       NaN       NaN       NaN          NaN    -1.274486
2019-50 -0.090451  0.022198 -0.231182          NaN     0.130683
2019-51  0.164583 -0.104173  0.016565          NaN    -1.274486
2019-52 -1.088672 -1.274486 -1.284807    -0.090451          NaN
2020-01  0.211166  0.130683 -0.350436     0.164583          NaN
2020-02 -1.088672 -1.274486 -1.284807    -1.088672          NaN
2020-03       NaN       NaN       NaN     0.211166          NaN
2020-04       NaN       NaN       NaN    -1.088672          NaN
```

Another idea with slicing index values, only necessary first generate default index by years:

```
N1 = 2
N2 = 3

y1 = 2000
y2 = 2025

a = [f"{year}-{week:02d}" for year in range(y1, y2 + 1) for week in range(1, 53)]
idx = df.reindex(a).index

new = idx[idx.get_loc(df.index[0]) - N2: idx.get_loc(df.index[-1])+ N2]


df = df.reindex(new)
df['x1_lagging2'] = df['x1'].shift(N1)
df['x2_leading3'] = df['x2'].shift(-N2)

print (df)
               x1        x2         y  x1_lagging2  x2_leading3
2019-47       NaN       NaN       NaN          NaN     0.022198
2019-48       NaN       NaN       NaN          NaN    -0.104173
2019-49       NaN       NaN       NaN          NaN    -1.274486
2019-50 -0.090451  0.022198 -0.231182          NaN     0.130683
2019-51  0.164583 -0.104173  0.016565          NaN    -1.274486
2019-52 -1.088672 -1.274486 -1.284807    -0.090451          NaN
2020-01  0.211166  0.130683 -0.350436     0.164583          NaN
2020-02 -1.088672 -1.274486 -1.284807    -1.088672          NaN
2020-03       NaN       NaN       NaN     0.211166          NaN
2020-04       NaN       NaN       NaN    -1.088672          NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry I don't understand why do you use `'%Y-%W %w'` as `idx`?

Comment: @ahbon this is a way to convert the Year-week format into an actual date (which I had used in my answer). `to_datetime` requires to have the day for the conversion. In general in pandas it's better to use datetime aware object rather than strings.

Comment: Yes, my data is weekly frequency, and in order to calculate the year-on-year growth rate, I divide each year's data into 52 weeks, and data beyond the 52nd week are counted to the 52nd week.